# Why is my List not being recognized as it has been initialized in onDraw()?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I have initialized my List in the function below in `MainActivity`with `DataPoint`(data class in GraphView)

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var graph_view = GraphView(this)
    graph_view.setData(generateRandomDataPoints())
    
}

fun generateRandomDataPoints(): List<GraphView.DataPoint> {
    val random = Random()
    return (0..20).map {
        GraphView.DataPoint(it, random.nextInt(50) + 1)
    }
}
```

}

**GraphView**

```
private val dataSet = arrayListOf<DataPoint>()
private var xMin = 0
private var xMax = 0
private var yMin = 0
private var yMax = 0

private val dataPointPaint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.BLACK

}


override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    Log.e("D SIze", dataSet.size.toString())

    for(i in 0 until dataSet.size){
        val realX = dataSet[i].xVal.toRealX()
        val realY = dataSet[i].yVal.toRealY()
        Log.e("TAG", realX.toString())
        Log.e("TAG", realY.toString())
        Log.e("TAG", "NOT BEingf claeed")

        canvas.drawCircle(realX, realY, 17f, dataPointPaint)
    }

}

fun setData(newDataSet: List<DataPoint>) {
    Log.e("TAG", newDataSet.size.toString())

    xMin = newDataSet.minByOrNull { it.xVal }?.xVal ?: 0
    xMax = newDataSet.maxByOrNull { it.xVal }?.xVal ?: 0
    yMin = newDataSet.minByOrNull { it.yVal }?.yVal ?: 0
    yMax = newDataSet.maxByOrNull { it.yVal }?.yVal ?: 0

    dataSet.clear() // clear if any point are entered
    dataSet.addAll(newDataSet) // add all points fro newDataSet

    for(i in 0 .. dataSet.size-1){
        Log.e("!!!!", dataSet[i].toString() )
    }
    invalidate()
}
private fun Int.toRealX() = toFloat() / xMax * width
private fun Int.toRealY() = toFloat() / yMax * height

data class DataPoint(
    val xVal: Int,
    val yVal: Int)
}
```

All of my logs work as expected and print's what is expected.

But when `onDraw()` is called from the `invalidate()` in the `setData()` function the log at the start returns 0. Which is why the `for` loop in `onDraw()` is never called and no points dots are being printed to the canvas?

I do not know why as all my other logs show that the data has been added for example the `for` loop in `setData()` prints

```
DataPoint(xVal=1, yVal=20)
DataPoint(xVal=3, yVal=37)
DataPoint(xVal=4, yVal=39)
....
```

Why is this and how can I solve it please?

Comment: Seems like you might be inadvertently ending up with multiple instances of `GraphView`. Please add the `MainActivity` class. Btw, you want to tag this with `[android]` rather than `[android-studio]`, since it's not really about the IDE.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the tag and added the MainActivity.

Comment: Yeah, `graph_view` there is not the `GraphView` that's (presumably) in your `activity_main` layout. If you do indeed have one in that layout, you want to add an `android:id` attribute to it, and use `findViewById()` to get it, instead of doing `GraphView(this)`. Make sense?

Comment: @MikeM. Got it thanks for the help